# Icon inside angular 2 component no longer working

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

Updated to "ionic-framework": "2.0.0-alpha.53" from a much earlier version. And added this dependency: "ionicons": "3.0.0-alpha.3".

I was using this in my html for an Angular 2 component. There is no ionic content in this html other than me trying to use the ion icons.

```
<div class="saveButton icon ion-md-add"
    (click)="onSaveSelected()"></div>
```

This worked in alpha 42. How do i use ionic icons in an angular 2 component? I have tried the following:

```
<div class="saveButton icon ion-md-add"
    (click)="onSaveSelected()">

    <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
</div>
```

This just shows a blank div.

Whenever i use this line `<ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>` inside of a `<ion-menu>` it works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [From Ionic Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/icon-inside-angular-2-component-no-longer-working/42641)
>
> If it is a custom component you need to include IONIC_DIRECTIVES in
>   the component:
>
> ```
> import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
> import {IONIC_DIRECTIVES} from 'ionic/ionic';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'my-component'
>   template: `<div class="my-style">
>               <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
>             </div>`,
>   directives: [IONIC_DIRECTIVES]
> })
> export class MyCustomComponent {}
> ```
>
> [Ionic Page Directives.](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/decorators/Page/)